# what value should i set to turn the phone to landscape mode?

Tags: android

In android, we can set the value 0/1 to orientation Accelerometer to lock the phone at portrait mode or rotate based on sensor state.   I have make vary searching on the web but i can't find what value i should set to lock the phone at landscape mode. Some one can help me?

```
        android.provider.Settings.System.putInt( getContentResolver(),
                                                 android.provider.Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION,
                                                 isLocking ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

set above line after your setContentView(view); this will set you device orientation of that activity to landscape

Comment: Refer this link   http://russenreaktor.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/solved-set-screen-orientation-programmatically/

Comment: Agarwal, when I said that I wanna lock the phone at landscape mode, I mean that all other applications should run at this mode. The code you give me just lock the current app at this mode, not all apps on the device. (That is a feature of existed app called "Rotation Locker". I am building an demo app similar with this but I don't know how to do).

Comment: Yes, It is. Currently I can lock the device at portrait mode but in landscape I can't.

Comment: So, dont you have any solution?